# WPF DG- How to delete selected row on Button click event from DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have the following problem.

I select a row from my DataGrid with mouse click like this:
Admin admin=(Admin)dGrid.SelectedItem;

How can I remove this row with button click event? I couldn't use Rows.Delete and didn't find any delete,remove commands in WPF. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding your DataGrid to an observable collection (in two ways mode) then removing the selected item from the collection is all what you need to do;
here is an example of how to proceed (DoubleClick To delete):

```
 <Grid>     
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AdminCollection,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAdmin}" MouseDoubleClick="DeleteRowEvent" >           
    </DataGrid>        
</Grid>
```

and the corresponding code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Admin _selectedAdmin = new Admin();
    public Admin SelectedAdmin
    {
        get { return _selectedAdmin; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedAdmin == value) return;
            _selectedAdmin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Admin> _adminCollection = new ObservableCollection<Admin>();
    public ObservableCollection<Admin> AdminCollection
    {
        get { return _adminCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (_adminCollection == value) return;
            _adminCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AdminCollection = new ObservableCollection<Admin>()
    {
        new Admin()
        {
            Name = "James",Age = 34, Location = "Paris"
        },
         new Admin()
        {
            Name = "Joe",Age = 34, Location = "Us"
        },
         new Admin()
        {
            Name = "Ann",Age = 34, Location = "Canada"
        },
    };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void DeleteRowEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        AdminCollection.Remove(AdminCollection.First(x => x.Id == SelectedAdmin.Id));
    }
}
public class Admin
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

the DataContext is set to the code behind in the MainWindow.xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Joseph,I tried your code,I didn't get any data into my DG. I know what is the problem,but I don't know how to solve it. So you set new value under the AdminCollection = new ObservableCollection<Admin>()
    {new Admin()
        {...}}; I understand your code,but I don't know how should I replace the ... part in it because I already gave value to all of my fields earlier through SQLQuery using LINQ. So what you do under the new Admin() exactly if you gave value already to all of your fields? Tried AdminCollection = new ObservableCollection<Admin>(); also.

Comment: just instanciate the Observable Collection using the List returned from the linq query : AdminCollection = new ObservableCollection<Admin>((linq query).toList)

Comment: Ok I did what you said,now that part is ok. But I didn't get any data,so I used some breakpoints. The AdminCollection is the problem,it says count=0 when I move on it with a cursor as the program runs (The selectedadmin is ok,it knows how many rows I have in the table and the rest of my code give back the data source when I run it with breakpoint). The rest find the table. Working on It,if I can make it work,I will accept your answer as a solution! :) If you have any idea,please share it with me. And I really appreciate your help Joseph!

Comment: i can't help unless i see the code, post a new question and point me to it! (you are welcome )

Comment: Thanks,it works,however it only delete the DataGrid rows,but the data is still in my database. Thanks anyway, you helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you bound your data to the DataGrid.

Since it looks like you bound an enumerable of Admin type, the you should find it in your list and remove it. Then the DataGrid should update.

Answer (score 0):

if u create manually datagrid and using linq then u can try it

like that :-

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_grid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="326" Width="946">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" Uid="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,31,0,0" IsReadOnly="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RegId}" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Registration Id" Width="sizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Name" Width="sizeToHeader" />

         <--Many column here-->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Row">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Row">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>   
</Grid>
```

and here is .cs code

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gridDataContext gcdd = new gridDataContext();
        registration RegistrationRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as registration;
        var Registration = (from p in gcdd.registrations where p.RegId == RegistrationRow.RegId select p).Single();
        gcdd.registrations.DeleteOnSubmit(Registration);
        gcdd.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Row Deleted Successfully");
        LoadCustomerDetail();
    }
```